# How to print some part of blade file in Laravel with domPDF

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I have to create a pdf file with Laravel. So I install in my composer domPDF. But I have to generate the pdf with only some parts of my blade file. I've already tried to create a new blade file and include it in the old blade file, but this return to me errors as the new blade file can't get the data I passed with the controller, so what can I do?

This is the function I wrote

```
    public function printPDF(){
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pages.newblade');
    return $pdf->download('document.pdf');
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Do some code refactor to pass the data to this subview, then generate the PDF.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting an option to refactor your code like this

```
public function printPDF(){
    $printthis = true;
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pages.newblade', compact('printthis'));
    return $pdf->download('document.pdf');
}
```

on `pages.newblade` check `printthis` variable if present means show the printable content else show all like this

```
   @if(isset($printthis))
        //printable code goes here
   @else
        //General code goes here
   @endif
```

Comment: This return to me errors, Undefined variable $printthis.

Comment: add printthis in printPDF method

Comment: Now I haven't error but the pdf generated is an empty page